# How to setup gRPC for AWS Kubernetes services

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, linkerd

Any idea how to setup gRPC for Kubernetes exposed services? We have deployed Linkerd in our cluster and that seems to work well and give us gRPC within Kubernetes. However we haven't found a solution that gives us gRPC connectivity from outside the cluster.